# spring boot to Tomcat deployment data source issue

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am building an application with Spring Boot, Neo4j and MongoDB. I have used @Configuration annotation to load database properties from application.properties like this:

```
@Bean(name = "neoDriver")
@Profile("local")
public Driver getNeoDriver() {

    return GraphDatabase.driver(
      env.getProperty("datasource.neo4j.uri"),
      AuthTokens.basic(env.getProperty("datasource.neo4j.username"), env.getProperty("datasource.neo4j.password")),
      Config.build().toConfig());
}
```

The autowire code is

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("neoDriver")
private Driver neoDriver;
```

when I run the application from IntelliJ, it runs fine; but when I try deploy the war file on Tomcat 8.5, it gives error.

```
Field neoDriver in com......repository.PositionRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver' that could not be found.

Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'positionService'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Service': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'positionRepository'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'RepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'neoDriver'; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=neoDriver)}
```

Please let me know what did I do wrong when deploying this on Tomcat.

Comment: suppose their is a good example about spring boot and Neo4J in github. refer this [post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-neo4j)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're not setting `spring.profiles.active` to `local` in your Tomcat deployment. Because your bean is marked with the `@Profile` annotation, so it will only be created if that profile is active.